# SYMGS implementation in CUDA

Tags: performance, c, cuda

I've been asked to implement one iteration of the Symmetric Gauss Seidel on CUDA.

I was given the CPU implementation for Sparse matrices in CSR and the goal to speed it up using the GPU.

Below is my implementation. Do you have any suggestions that can speed the CUDA part of the code? (I'm not allowed to change the input parsing function and the CPU code)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define MAX_CUDA_THREADS 1408   //CUDA

// Macro definition for nvidia error checking
#define CHECK(call)                                                                       \
    {                                                                                     \
        const cudaError_t err = call;                                                     \
        if (err != cudaSuccess)                                                           \
        {                                                                                 \
            printf("%s in %s at line %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(err), __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                           \
        }                                                                                 \
    }

#define CHECK_KERNELCALL()                                                                \
    {                                                                                     \
        const cudaError_t err = cudaGetLastError();                                       \
        if (err != cudaSuccess)                                                           \
        {                                                                                 \
            printf("%s in %s at line %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(err), __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                           \
        }                                                                                 \
    }

// function to get the time of day in seconds
double get_time(){ 
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return tv.tv_sec + tv.tv_usec * 1e-6;
}

// Reads a sparse matrix and represents it using CSR (Compressed Sparse Row) format
void read_matrix(int **row_ptr, int **col_ind, float **values, float **matrixDiagonal, const char *filename, int *num_rows, int *num_cols, int *num_vals)
{
    //int err;
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "File cannot be opened!\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    // Get number of rows, columns, and non-zero values
    if(fscanf(file, "%d %d %d\n", num_rows, num_cols, num_vals)==EOF)
        printf("Error reading file");

    int *row_ptr_t = (int *)malloc((*num_rows + 1) * sizeof(int));
    int *col_ind_t = (int *)malloc(*num_vals * sizeof(int));
    float *values_t = (float *)malloc(*num_vals * sizeof(float));
    float *matrixDiagonal_t = (float *)malloc(*num_rows * sizeof(float));
    // Collect occurances of each row for determining the indices of row_ptr
    int *row_occurances = (int *)malloc(*num_rows * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < *num_rows; i++)
    {
        row_occurances[i] = 0;
    }

    int row, column;
    float value;
    while (fscanf(file, "%d %d %f\n", &row, &column, &value) != EOF)
    {
        // Subtract 1 from row and column indices to match C format
        row--;
        column--;
        row_occurances[row]++;
    }

    // Set row_ptr
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < *num_rows; i++)
    {
        row_ptr_t[i] = index;
        index += row_occurances[i];
    }
    row_ptr_t[*num_rows] = *num_vals;
    free(row_occurances);

    // Set the file position to the beginning of the file
    rewind(file);

    // Read the file again, save column indices and values
    for (int i = 0; i < *num_vals; i++)
    {
        col_ind_t[i] = -1;
    }

    if(fscanf(file, "%d %d %d\n", num_rows, num_cols, num_vals)==EOF)
        printf("Error reading file");
    
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (fscanf(file, "%d %d %f\n", &row, &column, &value) != EOF)
    {
        row--;
        column--;

        // Find the correct index (i + row_ptr_t[row]) using both row information and an index i
        while (col_ind_t[i + row_ptr_t[row]] != -1)
        {
            i++;
        }
        col_ind_t[i + row_ptr_t[row]] = column;
        values_t[i + row_ptr_t[row]] = value;
        if (row == column)
        {
            matrixDiagonal_t[j] = value;
            j++;
        }
        i = 0;
    }
    fclose(file);
    *row_ptr = row_ptr_t;
    *col_ind = col_ind_t;
    *values = values_t;
    *matrixDiagonal = matrixDiagonal_t;
}

// CPU implementation of SYMGS using CSR, DO NOT CHANGE THIS
void symgs_csr_sw(const int *row_ptr, const int *col_ind, const float *values, const int num_rows, float *x, float *matrixDiagonal)
{

    // forward sweep
    for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++)
    {
        float sum = x[i];
        const int row_start = row_ptr[i];
        const int row_end = row_ptr[i + 1];
        float currentDiagonal = matrixDiagonal[i]; // Current diagonal value

        for (int j = row_start; j < row_end; j++)
        {
            sum -= values[j] * x[col_ind[j]];
        }

        sum += x[i] * currentDiagonal; // Remove diagonal contribution from previous loop

        x[i] = sum / currentDiagonal;
    }

    // backward sweep
    for (int i = num_rows - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        float sum = x[i];
        const int row_start = row_ptr[i];
        const int row_end = row_ptr[i + 1];
        float currentDiagonal = matrixDiagonal[i]; // Current diagonal value

        for (int j = row_start; j < row_end; j++)
        {
            sum -= values[j] * x[col_ind[j]];
        }
        sum += x[i] * currentDiagonal; // Remove diagonal contribution from previous loop

        x[i] = sum / currentDiagonal;
    }
    
}

// Gets the accuracy of gpu against cpu (0.1% treshold for relative error)
void get_accuracy(float *x_gpu, float *x, int num_rows){
    double acc, err;
    int num;
    for(int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++){
        err = (x_gpu[i] - x[i]) / x[i];
        if(err > 0.1 || err < -0.1){
            num++;
        }
    }
    acc = 100.0 - ((double) num / num_rows) * 100.0;
    printf("Accuracy (treshold: 0.1%% relative error): %.3f%%\n", acc);
}

__global__
void parallel_symgs_fw(
                        const int *row_ptr, 
                        const int *col_ind, 
                        const float *values, 
                        const int num_rows, 
                        float *matrixDiagonal,
                        float *old_x,
                        float *new_x,
                        bool *updated)
{
    int row_index = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    if(row_index >= num_rows || updated[row_index]) return;

    float sum = old_x[row_index];
    int row_start = row_ptr[row_index];
    int row_stop = row_ptr[row_index + 1];
    float currDiag = matrixDiagonal[row_index];
    bool row_ready = true;

    for(int i = row_start; 
        i < row_stop;   
        i++)
    {
        if(!row_ready) break;                                   // Row isn't ready, abort all row calcs
        if(col_ind[i] < 0) continue;                            // Out of bound value to be handled
        if(col_ind[i] >= row_index)                             // If the value is above the main diag, it has no dep
            sum -= values[i] * old_x[col_ind[i]];
        else if (updated[col_ind[i]])                           // If dep has already been updated, use it
            sum -= values[i] * new_x[col_ind[i]];
        else 
            row_ready = false;                                  // Otherwise lower the row ready flag
    }
    if (row_ready)                                              // If row ready is raised after whole row, row has finished
    {
        sum += old_x[row_index] * currDiag;                     // Remove diagonal contribution
        new_x[row_index] = sum / currDiag;                      // Update x value
        updated[row_index] = true;                              // Raise the updated value of the row
    }
    else updated[num_rows] = false;                             // Otherwise set done to false (new iteration is needed)
}

__global__
void parallel_symgs_bw(
                        const int *row_ptr, 
                        const int *col_ind, 
                        const float *values, 
                        const int num_rows, 
                        float *matrixDiagonal,
                        float *old_x,
                        float *new_x,
                        bool *updated)
{
    int row_index = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
    if(row_index >= num_rows || updated[row_index]) return;

    float sum = new_x[row_index];
    int row_start = row_ptr[row_index];
    int row_stop = row_ptr[row_index + 1];
    float currDiag = matrixDiagonal[row_index];
    bool row_ready = true;

    for(int i = row_start; 
        i < row_stop;   
        i++)
    {
        if(!row_ready) break;                                   // Row isn't ready, abort all row calcs
        if(col_ind[i] < 0) continue;                            // Out of bound value to be handled
        if(col_ind[i] <= row_index)                             // If the value is below the main diag, it has no dep
            sum -= values[i] * new_x[col_ind[i]];
        else if (updated[col_ind[i]])                           // If dep has already been updated, use it
            sum -= values[i] * old_x[col_ind[i]];
        else 
            row_ready = false;                                  // Otherwise lower the row ready flag
    }
    if (row_ready)                                              // If row ready is raised after whole row, row has finished
    {
        sum += new_x[row_index] * currDiag;                     // Remove diagonal contribution
        old_x[row_index] = sum / currDiag;                      // Update x value
        updated[row_index] = true;                             // Raise the updated value of the row
    }
    else updated[num_rows] = false;                              // Otherwise set done to false (new iteration is needed)
}

void symgs_csr_kernel(
                        const int *row_ptr, 
                        const int *col_ind, 
                        const float *values, 
                        const int num_rows,
                        float *matrixDiagonal,
                        int num_vals,
                        int threads_per_block,
                        float *x_gpu,
                        double *start,
                        double *end)
{

    int *d_row_ptr, *d_col_ind;
    float *d_matrixDiagonal, *d_new_x, *d_old_x, *d_values;
    bool *d_updated;
    bool done;
    
    // Device mem allocation
    CHECK(cudaMalloc(&d_row_ptr, (num_rows + 1) * sizeof(int)));
    CHECK(cudaMalloc(&d_col_ind, num_vals * sizeof(int)));
    CHECK(cudaMalloc(&d_values, num_vals * sizeof(float)));
    CHECK(cudaMalloc(&d_matrixDiagonal, num_rows * sizeof(float)));
    CHECK(cudaMalloc(&d_new_x, num_rows * sizeof(float)));
    CHECK(cudaMalloc(&d_old_x, num_rows * sizeof(float)))
    CHECK(cudaMalloc(&d_updated, num_rows * sizeof(bool) + 1));

    // Array init for the updated flag
    // Last pos of array is a flag that gets lowered by the device
    // when the sweep has not been completed and needs to be reiterated
    CHECK(cudaMemset(d_updated, 0, num_rows * sizeof(bool) + 1));

    // Matrix data copy from host memory to device memory
    CHECK(cudaMemcpy(d_row_ptr, row_ptr, (num_rows + 1) * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDefault));
    CHECK(cudaMemcpy(d_col_ind, col_ind, num_vals * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDefault));
    CHECK(cudaMemcpy(d_values, values, num_vals * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDefault));
    CHECK(cudaMemcpy(d_matrixDiagonal, matrixDiagonal, num_rows * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDefault));
    CHECK(cudaMemcpy(d_old_x, x_gpu, num_rows * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDefault));

    int num_blocks = num_rows / threads_per_block + 1;
    dim3 dimGrid(num_blocks, 1, 1);
    dim3 dimBlock(threads_per_block, 1, 1);

    *start = get_time();
    //Iterate forward sweep until all rows are done
    //Ignore rows which have dependecies not already calculated
    do
    {
        CHECK(cudaMemset(d_updated + num_rows, 1, sizeof(bool)));                       // Set done -> 1
        parallel_symgs_fw<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(                                       // Kernel call
            d_row_ptr, 
            d_col_ind, 
            d_values, 
            num_rows,
            d_matrixDiagonal,
            d_old_x, 
            d_new_x,
            d_updated);
        CHECK_KERNELCALL();
        CHECK(cudaMemcpy(&done, d_updated + num_rows, sizeof(bool), cudaMemcpyDefault));//copy back done flag
    } while (!done);
    
    //Reset flag array
    CHECK(cudaMemset(d_updated, 0, num_rows * sizeof(bool)));

    //Iterate backward sweep until all rows are done
    //Ignore rows which have dependencies not already calculated
    do{
        CHECK(cudaMemset(d_updated + num_rows, 1, sizeof(bool)));                       // Set done -> 1
        parallel_symgs_bw<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(                                       // Kernel call
            d_row_ptr, 
            d_col_ind, 
            d_values, 
            num_rows,
            d_matrixDiagonal,
            d_old_x,
            d_new_x,
            d_updated);
        CHECK_KERNELCALL();
        CHECK(cudaMemcpy(&done, d_updated + num_rows, sizeof(bool), cudaMemcpyDefault));//Copy back done flag
    }while (!done);

    CHECK(cudaMemcpy(x_gpu, d_old_x, num_rows * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDefault));

    *end = get_time();

    // CUDA Free
    CHECK(cudaFree(d_row_ptr));
    CHECK(cudaFree(d_col_ind));
    CHECK(cudaFree(d_matrixDiagonal));
    CHECK(cudaFree(d_values));
    CHECK(cudaFree(d_new_x));
    CHECK(cudaFree(d_old_x));
    CHECK(cudaFree(d_updated));
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./exec matrix_file threads_per_block");
        return 0;
    }

    int *row_ptr, *col_ind, num_rows, num_cols, num_vals;
    float *values;
    float *matrixDiagonal;

    const char *filename = argv[1];
    int threads_per_block = atoi(argv[2]);

    double start_input, end_input;
    double start_cpu, end_cpu;
    double start_gpu, end_gpu;

    start_input = get_time();
    read_matrix(&row_ptr, &col_ind, &values, &matrixDiagonal, filename, &num_rows, &num_cols, &num_vals);
    end_input = get_time();

    float *x = (float *)malloc(num_rows * sizeof(float));
    float *x_gpu = (float *)malloc(num_rows * sizeof(float));

    // Generate a random vector
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++)
    {
        x[i] = (float)(rand() % 100) / (rand() % 100 + 1); // the number we use to divide cannot be 0, that's the reason of the +1
        x_gpu[i] = x[i];
    }

    // CPU
    start_cpu = get_time();
    symgs_csr_sw(row_ptr, col_ind, values, num_rows, x, matrixDiagonal);
    end_cpu = get_time();

    // GPU
    symgs_csr_kernel(
        row_ptr,
        col_ind,
        values,
        num_rows,
        matrixDiagonal,
        num_vals,
        threads_per_block,
        x_gpu,
        &start_gpu,
        &end_gpu
    );

    // Print timings
    printf("SYMGS Time INPUT: %.10lf\n", end_input - start_input);
    printf("SYMGS Time CPU: %.10lf\n", end_cpu - start_cpu);
    printf("SYMGS Time GPU: %.10lf\n", end_gpu - start_gpu);

    //Print accuracy
    get_accuracy(x_gpu, x, num_rows);

    // Free
    free(row_ptr);
    free(col_ind);
    free(values);
    free(matrixDiagonal);
    free(x);
    free(x_gpu);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: "Do you have any suggestions that can speed it up?" --> Does that allow changes to `// CPU implementation of SYMGS using CSR, DO NOT CHANGE THIS
void symgs_csr_sw()`?

Comment: No, I can only modify my solution which is the CUDA code.

Comment: Do you always get the same accuracy for every run? Or better, because the accuracy has some wiggle room: do you always get the same result with your GPU code? The checking and setting of `updated` feels dangerous.

Answer (score 3):

> Do you have any suggestions that can speed it up?

First, remove coding weaknesses

**Check against expected value, not just one of the undesired values.**

```
// while (fscanf(file, "%d %d %f\n", &row, &column, &value) != EOF)
while (fscanf(file, "%d %d %f\n", &row, &column, &value) == 3)

// if(fscanf(file, "%d %d %d\n", num_rows, num_cols, num_vals)==EOF)
if(fscanf(file, "%d %d %d\n", num_rows, num_cols, num_vals) != 3)

// while (fscanf(file, "%d %d %f\n", &row, &column, &value) != EOF)
while (fscanf(file, "%d %d %f\n", &row, &column, &value) == 3)
```

**Check allocation success**

Also cast not needed and size to the referenced object, not type.

```
// int *row_ptr_t = (int *)malloc((*num_rows + 1) * sizeof(int));
int *row_ptr_t = malloc(sizeof row_ptr_t[0] * (*num_rows + 1u));
if (row_ptr_t == NULL) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory\n");
  return;
}
```

4 other places too.

---

**Use `restrict`**

When calling code uses pointers to **different** areas of memory, use `restrict` to let the compiler know that code like `new_x[row_index] = sum / currDiag;` that changes `new_x[]` does *not* change the other referenced data.  This allows the compiler to optimize and maybe even parallelized code.

```
// void parallel_symgs_fw(const int *row_ptr, const int *col_ind, 
//     const float *values, const int num_rows, 
//     float *matrixDiagonal, float *old_x, float *new_x,                        
//     bool *updated) {
void parallel_symgs_fw(const int * restrict row_ptr, const int * restrict col_ind, 
    const float * restrict values, const int num_rows, 
    float * restrict matrixDiagonal, float * restrict old_x, float * restrict new_x,                        
    bool * restrict updated) {
```

This and other functions.

**Minor: Simplify and avoid `double` math**

- Use `const`
- Use `float` constants.
- Test loop against 0

```
// void get_accuracy(float *x_gpu, float *x, int num_rows){
void get_accuracy(const float *x_gpu, const float *x, int num_rows){
    double acc, err;
    int num;
    // for(int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++){
    for (int i = num_rows; i-- > 0; ) {
        // err = (x_gpu[i] - x[i]) / x[i];
        // if(err > 0.1 || err < -0.1) { num++; }
        err = (x_gpu[i] - x[i]) / x[i];
        if (fabsf(err) > 0.01f) { num++; }
    }
    acc = 100.0 - ((double) num / num_rows) * 100.0;
    // printf("Accuracy (treshold: 0.1%% relative error): %.3f%%\n", acc);
    // Spell check
    printf("Accuracy (threshold: 0.1%% relative error): %.3f%%\n", acc);
}
```